# What IP address does Ubuntu assign itself when it cannot reach a DHCP server?

Tags: networking, dhcp, ip

When Windows is attached to a network but cannot reach a DHCP server, it [defaults to an IP address](https://superuser.com/questions/238625/why-is-windows-default-ip-address-169-xx-xx-xx) of the form 169.254.XXX.XXX.

Does Ubuntu do something similiar?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Ubuntu does that, too, if you use NetworkManager to manage your network interfaces (that's the default for most graphical environments in Ubuntu).

It is a common standard defined in [RFC3927](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3927) and used by most modern operating systems.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! But what if I run Ubuntu server edition as a headless system?

Comment: The server edition doesn't do that by default but only uses the configuration in ``/etc/network/interfaces``. If you don't have a DHCP server you usually use static IP addresses. See chapter [Network Configuration](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/network-configuration.html) in the Server Guide for how to do this.

Comment: So what happens if that file specifies `iface eth0 inet dhcp`, but no dhcp server is present? I am sorry to press this point, but this is actually what I (might) be dealing with.

Comment: Then `eth0` gets no IP address at all.